# SQl trigger after insert issue

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am working on triggers using SQL server 2005. I have a trigger for a table which is after update. After declaring the variables, the code is like this.

```
if @isconfirmed_before = 0 and @isconfirmed_after = 1
begin

if @invite_userid <> ''
        begin

            select @points = points from dbo.InvitePoint where code = 'USR' and packageid = @packageid
            INSERT INTO InviteCount
                   ([userID]
                   ,[joinMerchantID]
                   ,[packageID]
                   ,[points]
                   ,[joinDate])
             VALUES
                   (@invite_userid
                   ,@merchantid
                   ,@packageid
                   ,@points
                   ,getdate())
        end

 SET @alpha_numeric=''
        SELECT @alpha_numeric=@alpha_numeric+CHAR(n) FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP 8 number AS n FROM master..spt_values
            WHERE TYPE='p' and (number between 48 and 57 or number between 65 and 90)
            ORDER BY NEWID()
        ) AS t 

        update merchant
        set reg_code = @alpha_numeric
        where merchantid = @merchantid

END
```

The last part of

```
    update merchant  
    set reg_code = @alpha_numeric
    where merchantid = @merchantid
```

This reg_code shoule be inserted only once when the row is inserted but it is changing every time there is an update to the table. How do i make it happen. Please help me, Thank you in advance!!

Comment: give the full code for the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update merchant   
set reg_code = @alpha_numeric 
where merchantid = @merchantid
```

That code is executing every time there is an update, because you have no conditional flow preventing it from executing sometimes.  If you want to only execute that given a certain condition, you'll need to wrap it in an `IF` block.

You say: "This reg_code shoule be inserted only once when the row is inserted but it is changing every time there is an update to the table."  Why is that in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger then?  It looks like it should be in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger.  Unless I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: There are lot of other statements in the trigger which should run after each update. So i have created a new trigger for after insert. It worked fine. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

OK you are very much in trouble with triggers.  First you need to show the actual create trigger code. I suspect you don't have it set correctly to only fire on insert.

Next you need to assume that the trigger must be able to handle multiple record inserts. Anytime you are setting a value to a scalar variable in a trigger, you are probably doing something wrong. This can't be your whole trigger either because you haven't shown how you get the varible values.